# How to get array items from array object by key value in php

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects as bellow:

```
$ARR =[
{"id":55,"timetable_id":1,"day":"Sat","checkin":"07:00:00","checkout":"11:00:00","isActive":1,"created_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23","updated_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23"},
{"id":54,"timetable_id":1,"day":"Fri","checkin":"07:00:00","checkout":"11:00:00","isActive":1,"created_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23","updated_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23"},
{"id":53,"timetable_id":1,"day":"Thu","checkin":"07:00:00","checkout":"11:00:00","isActive":1,"created_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23","updated_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23"},
{"id":52,"timetable_id":1,"day":"Wed","checkin":"07:00:00","checkout":"11:00:00","isActive":1,"created_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23","updated_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23"},
{"id":51,"timetable_id":1,"day":"Tue","checkin":"14:00:00","checkout":"17:00:00","isActive":1,"created_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23","updated_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23"},
{"id":50,"timetable_id":1,"day":"Tue","checkin":"07:00:00","checkout":"11:00:00","isActive":1,"created_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23","updated_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23"},
{"id":49,"timetable_id":1,"day":"Mon","checkin":"14:00:00","checkout":"16:00:00","isActive":1,"created_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23","updated_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23"},
{"id":48,"timetable_id":1,"day":"Mon","checkin":"07:00:00","checkout":"11:00:00","isActive":1,"created_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23","updated_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23"}
];
```

And I want to get any array items by the specific key value. 
For example I want to get the items of the key `day` that equal to `Tue`, so my array result will look like:

```
$RESULTS=[
    {"id":51,"timetable_id":1,"day":"Tue","checkin":"14:00:00","checkout":"17:00:00","isActive":1,"created_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23","updated_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23"},
    {"id":50,"timetable_id":1,"day":"Tue","checkin":"07:00:00","checkout":"11:00:00","isActive":1,"created_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23","updated_at":"2017-12-28 19:40:23"},
    ];
```

---

### What I have tried:

```
$RESULTS = [];
foreach($ARR as $item){
   if($item->day == 'Tue'){
     $RESULTS[] = $item;
   }
}
```

Technically, it is working as expected, but it needs to write many line of code. Is there any other PHP functions that support this operation? I tried `array_slice` and `array_search` but no luck.

Comment: You call that _"many lines of code"_?

Comment: @Phil It's many lines of code if the OP has to repeat it over and over for different conditions.

Comment: @bishop I mean, you could encapsulate it into a function (which I figured OP already knows). You could also make it one line if you really wanted ~ `foreach($ARR as $i) if($item->day==='Tue') $RESULTS[]=$item;`

Comment: Interestingly, I assumed the OP hadn't considered a function: worrying over line count seemed the Y of the X-Y problem: "I have to do this many times and I don't want to repeat a lot of code: how can I do this in one line".

Answer (score 3):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with your implementation. The only other alternative I can think of is [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php)

```
$RESULTS = array_filter($ARR, function($item) {
    return $item->day === 'Tue';
});
```

There's a good chance your original approach is [more performant](http://www.levijackson.net/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/) than this though, especially across such a small array.

Note also that keys are preserved with `array_filter` so you'd end up with indexes 4 and 5. You can use `array_values` to re-index the array

```
$RESULTS = array_values($RESULTS);
```

Comment: Oh, for wishing PHP implemented short closures.

Comment: @bishop yup. Arrow functions / lambdas would sure be nice. Would also be nice if the `array_*` functions could work on the collection in parallel. For large data sets, we might actually see some performance benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to do this, but: if you need to do the same kind of thing many times, that calls for a function:

```
function pluck(array $ARR, $key, $value) {
    $RESULTS = [];
    foreach ($ARR as $item){
        if ($item->$key == $value) {
            $RESULTS[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $RESULTS;
}
```

Which you may then call as:

```
$RESULTS = pluck($ARR, 'day', 'Tue');
$RESULTS = pluck($ARR, 'isActive', 1);
// etc...
```

As many times as needed, without all the duplicated code. That said, of course, you may not want a strict `==` comparison, in which case you might opt for a function that's more flexible. For example, `$value` might be a regular expression, and your function could be modified so:

```
        if (preg_match($value, $item->$key) {
```